# How to write python global variables

Tags: python

I am trying to access a global variable in python inside a `function`, but it's value is not changing inside the function as apparently it doesn't refer to the global variable but it considers it a new variable.

here as below, I want to change the value of `is_new_namespace` = True`inside the function`test`

This is what I did and it doesn't recognize the variable but considers it as a newly created variable inside the function itself.

And one thing I need again is, can I access this variable `is_new_namespace`inside another `python` file in the same directory? if yes, how?

```
from BitesizeDecorator import BitesizeDecorator
import execute
import constants
import subprocess
from custom_check_kubectl import does_kubectl_work

class CreateNamesapce(BitesizeDecorator):

    def __init__(self, createnamesapce):
        super(CreateNamesapce, self).__init__(createnamesapce)

    is_new_namespace = False #global variable

    def test(self):
        super(CreateNamesapce, self).test()

        if does_kubectl_work(self) != 0: # works

            does_namespace_available = execute.check_if_exists("kubectl get ns | grep -E \'(^|\s)"+constants.NAMESPACE+"($|\s)\'")


            if does_namespace_available != "" and len(does_namespace_available) != 0 : #if exists
                print(constants.ORANGE+"\n[6] "+ u'\u0021' +constants.NC+" - "+constants.ORANGE+"Namespace \"" + constants.NAMESPACE +"\" already exists...\n" + constants.NC)
                print(does_namespace_available)
            else:


                is_new_namespace = True #function considers this as a newly created variable

                namespace_output = execute.subprocess_execute_arr(["kubectl", "create", "namespace", constants.NAMESPACE])

                if namespace_output == 0: # returns zero if executed successfully 
                    print(constants.GREEN+"\n[6] " + u'\u2714' +constants.NC+" - "+constants.GREEN+" Namespace " + constants.NAMESPACE + " created successfully..." + constants.NC + "\n")
                else:
                    print(constants.RED+"\n[6] " +  u'\u274C' +constants.NC+" - "+constants.RED+"error creating namespace \"" + constants.NAMESPACE + "\""+constants.NC+"\n")

        else:
            print(constants.RED + constants.ICON_CROSS + "  \"Kubectl\" commmands are not working\n" + constants.NC)
```

Comment: Since you created a class, the variable belongs to that class and is not "global". You need to reference it with self.is_new_namespace, or put it above your class definition

Comment: At the beginning of your function, write `global #variable name`

Comment: Also, variables usually go first in a class definition, above the `def __init__`

Comment: is your goal to make it global or be shared between all `CreateNamesapce` objects? you define it inside the class so you could refer to it as `CreateNamesapce. is_new_namespace` and change it that way. Where do you expect to be reading the variable?

Comment: I need to get this variable value to a different python file.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comments on your code below

```
class CreateNamesapce(BitesizeDecorator):

    def __init__(self, createnamesapce):
        super(CreateNamesapce, self).__init__(createnamesapce)

    # 1. this is a variable in this class, so it only exists in this class
    is_new_namespace = False

    def test(self):
        super(CreateNamesapce, self).test()

        # 2. this is treated as a new variable in this function only
        is_new_namespace = True

        # 3. this would properly reference and update the variable for the entire class, 
        # because of self (see comment 1.)
        self.is_new_namespace = True
```

Adding `is_new_namespace = False` ABOVE the class definition means you can use it anywhere in this same file as intended, without needing `self`. 
To reference this variable in other files, you would need to import it from wherever it was first created. For example, if your current code is in a file called `file_a.py` and you are in a new file called `file_b.py` you would need

```
from file_a import is_new_namespace
```

Now you have the variable that you created in `file_a`

Also, it is good practice to declare class variables first thing in the class, above `def __init__(self)`

```
class CreateNamesapce(BitesizeDecorator):

    # declare class variables here
    is_new_namespace = False

    def __init__(self, createnamesapce):
        super(CreateNamesapce, self).__init__(createnamesapce)
```